# Finding confusion in pointer in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a = 320;
    char *ptr;
    ptr =( char*)&a;
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I just wanted to know what is the use `(char*)`? What if I used `(int*)` instead of that?

Comment: You can certainly use `int*` instead. It all depends on what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is of type integer i.e. `int a = 320;`
Your pointer is of type character i.e. `char *ptr;`

character pointer can only points to character type variable, but you in your code want to point a integer variable so how would that be possible? By this line of code: `ptr =( char*)&a;` what it doing is type casting your pointer varble explicitly or forcefully (whatsoever you might want to call), by making it character type.

Answer (score 1):

Let's change the program a bit:

```
int main() {
    int a = 0x12345678;   // put hexadecimal value 12345678 into a
    char *charptr = (char*)&a;
    int *intptr = &a;                
    printf("%x\n", *charptr);   // %x prints in hexadecimal
    printf("%x\n", *intptr);
    return 0;
}
```

On a little endian system the output will be :

```
78
12345678
```

- `&a` is the memory address of the `a` variable.
- `charptr` is a pointer to `char`
- `intptr` is a pointer to `int`

The second output `12345678` is obvious, but the first output `78` is not quite as obvious.

On a [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system the int `a` in memory looks like this:

```
+----+
| 78 |  <---- both 'charptr' and 'intptr' point here
+----+
| 56 |
+----+
| 34 |
+----+
| 12 |
+----+
```

The char (or byte) at the address `&a` is 0x78, therefore if you dereference the `charptr` pointer you get `0x78`.

On a [big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) system we have this:

```
+----+
| 12 |  <---- both 'charptr' and 'intptr' point here
+----+
| 34 |
+----+
| 56 |
+----+
| 78 |
+----+
```

and the first output would be `12` instead of `78`.

---

In this line

```
char *charptr = (char*)&a;
```

the `(char*)` is called a cast, and it tells the compiler to consider `&a` as a pointer to `char`.

Without the cast:

```
char *charptr = &a;
```

you will get a compiler warning such as `incompatible types - from 'int *' to 'char *'`, because you are trying to assign a pointer to `int` to a pointer to `char`.

If you write this:

```
char *charptr = (int*)&a;
```

then you will also get a compiler warning `incompatible types - from 'int *' to 'char *'`. Anyway in that case the `(int*)` cast is useless because `&a` *is* already a pointer to `int`.

Comment: It is however not a good idea to use `char*` for this purpose, since it has implementation-defined signedness. Use `uint8_t*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

calling a variable `ptr` doesn't make it a pointer. if you want it to be a pointer it has to be declared with a * ie `int *ptr;` or `char *ptr;`

Casting a pointer such as `&a` to type `char` is just silly as they're totally different things. Using `(int *)` wouldn't change the type of `&a` so you'd not need to put it in, but then your compiler would show you that `ptr` is totally the wrong type for storing the value of `&a` in.